# Machine Learning Training data error match data

Tags: python, machine-learning

I want to train the model, but when I enter the x_test and y_test values for the score after the fit model, it gives me a mismatch error.

```
## This proje is my first personal project trying 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import sklearn

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, f1_score

train = pd.read_csv("/Users/ahmeteminguney/Desktop/house/train.csv")
home_test = pd.read_csv("/Users/ahmeteminguney/Desktop/house/test.csv")
home_result = pd.read_csv("/Users/ahmeteminguney/Desktop/house/sample_submission.csv")
x = train.drop("SalePrice", axis=1)
y = train["SalePrice"]
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,
                                                    y, 
                                                    test_size=0.2, 
                                                    )


all_data = pd.concat([x_train, home_test])
missing_columns = all_data.columns[all_data.isnull().any()].tolist()
def fill_missing_values(data):
    for column in missing_columns:
        if data[column].dtype == 'float64' or data[column].dtype == 'int64':
            data[column].fillna(data[column].mean(), inplace=True)
        else:
            data[column].fillna(data[column].mode()[0], inplace=True)
    return data


train_filled = fill_missing_values(train)
home_test_filled = fill_missing_values(home_test)

x_train = pd.get_dummies(x_train)
x_test = pd.get_dummies(x_test)
y_train = pd.get_dummies(y_train)
y_test = pd.get_dummies(y_test)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
model3 = KNeighborsClassifier()
model3.fit(x_train,y_train)
model3.score(x_test,y_test)`
```

ValueError: The feature names should match those that were passed during fit.
Feature names seen at fit time, yet now missing:

ı try a lot of way but ı didnt fix

Comment: You are being downvoted likely because **1)** _I try a lot_ doesn't tell us _what_ you tried, which may help us to understand the problem and to not repeat the steps that you have already tired. **2)** The error is quite explicit: training and test set feature names doesn't match. Did you check the feature names? Which ones didn't matched? Why do you think that happened?

Comment: Also, post always a [mre]. Your actual code has many imports that are not necessary for this problem and we don't have (nor we want) your csv files. Generate a small dataframe and paste it with `.to_dict` so we can reproduce the problem. BTW, you would probably have found and solve the problem yourself doing this, as you would have found that only test sets that hot-encode with different features than the training set can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using pandas' `get_dummies` in each data set. So, if a value is present in your test set, that was not present in the training set, it will generate a new feature instead of encode it as a row of zeros for the previously seen (training) features.

Use instead sklearn [`OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), fit it to (and transform) the training set, and then use the fit encoder to transform the test set.